# Selling a Force.com App on license base without publishing it in the AppExhchange

Tags: force.com, salesforce1-app, licenses, embedded

Imagine we have several requests from clients for custom Force.com apps. Surely we can build those and get paid once, but for continuity, we (and our client) like to have a licensing model where they pay us for every user/month. Note that we want the model such that the client only needs to pay us and does not need to already have Force.com / CRM licenses. We then pass a part of the revenue to Salesforce.

Salesforce offers ISV Partners the possibility to create such apps (Force.com embedded), however, as far as I know, you need to publish these apps to the AppExchange while, in contrast, for our clients we only want *them* to be able to install their app, and *nobody else*. I.e. we do not want an AppExchange listing.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce provides OEM User License model that can be useful here. In this model you get empty force.com orgs for your customer on which you can install your app and sell it to your customer and share revenue with Salesforce.

For more details take look at these links

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/oem_user_license_comparison.htm

[Salesforce OEM license restrictions for end users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28164/salesforce-oem-license-restrictions-for-end-users)

http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Difference-between-ISVForce-OEM-Apps-3774731.S.115652226

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oV9LthQ5O0

Comment: Yes that's possible, but it requires the other party to have existing Force.com / CRM Enterprise licenses, which is not what we want. We want the Force.com embedded model, where the client only pays us, and we pass a part of the revenue on to Salesforce. (I made this requirement clearer in the question now)

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. Is the OEM structure different from the Force.com Embedded that I mentioned in my post? And could you elaborate on how to not appear on the AppExchange? if so, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: This seems new question to me but let my try to answer it. OEM and Force.com Embedded are same thing. As per my understanding you can not appear on Appexchnage with OEM. You need to setup your own making site. Please go through the links they contain very good details about OEM.

Comment: It was in my question that we do not want to appear on the AppExchange :-) There's Force.com Embedded apps on the AppExchange, but indeed on the links you posted there's the suggestion that there are also Force.Com Embedded apps that are nót on the AppExchange. So at least I now know it's possible. I assume it works with a private listing, since we do need the LMA functionality. But I'll look into that, thanks so far!

Comment: I am 100% sure that there are OEM apps and those does not appear on AppExchange. In fact I am working for one such customer so can tell you for sure that private OEM app exist. Glad that those links helped.

Comment: Excellent! :-) Does that work with a private listing?!

Comment: yes, defiantly it works.