# Salesforce reseller programme / Partner programme - Apto app - how does work?

Tags: configuration, licenses

I came across this website - http://www.apto.com/. It seems to be Salesforce CRM which already has the org setup in such a way to benefit estate agencies the most.

I wasn't aware that this was possible? I thought the two routes with becoming a Salesforce partner were to either become a consultancy company via the Partner Programme or to upload a managed / unmanaged package to the AppExchange as a ISV Partner.

This seems to be re-selling Salesforce licenses at a markup, justified by a pre-configured org specifying a particular industry?

I wasn't aware that re-selling Salesforce licenses like this was a possibility?

Thanks

EDIT - some more interesting related information can be found here: [Salesforce OEM license restrictions for end users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28164/salesforce-oem-license-restrictions-for-end-users)

Comment: https://www.veeva.com/ -- One more example

Comment: [JobScience](http://www.jobscience.com/) is another one. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Salesforce allows you to build an application, called an OEM application, where your subscribers do not pay salesforce.com directly for licenses, but instead pay the OEM partner directly. In turn, the OEM partner pays a percentage of its license revenue to salesforce.com. Typically, salesforce.com loses a few bucks per license, but is still gaining revenue through volume licenses, and they don't have to deal with subscription costs, sales, marketing, etc. The standard OEM agreement prohibits Leads, Opportunities, Cases, etc (the "CRM" part of Salesforce), but allows custom objects, API access, and so on. The OEM wins because they no longer have to deal with hardware and platform software or system upgrades and maintenance, and can focus on building their purpose-built application. Here's [more information](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/oem_user_license_comparison.htm) about the OEM license types.

Comment: Thanks as always, @sfdcfox :) Do you know if there's a way for one to find out all the different OEM providers? Or is this information that Salesforce don't make publically available?

Comment: Also, as per the link 'OEM Embedded—A full Force.com license with contractual restrictions. It prohibits Create, Read, Update, and Delete on Leads, Opportunities, Cases, Solutions, and Campaigns' - that wouldn't restrict an OEM app from having custom objects which in effect 'mock' those objects?

Comment: @AndyHitchings (a) there's no public listing of OEM vendors that I'm aware of; they are forced to do their own marketing and sales. (b) That's the standard contract. In the past, it was possible to negotiate that, and may still be today. A previous company I worked at we had Opportunities, but not Leads, Cases, Solutions, or Campaigns. They may have since done away with that for new partners. (c) you're contractually obligated not to mock any restricted object, and they'll terminate the partnership if you violate your arrangement.

Comment: @AndyHitchings Honestly, if you want CRM + your own app, it's a *lot* less hassle to simply be an ISV partner instead (for you, not your clients). In the ISV arrangement, clients pay for CRM licenses to Salesforce, and license fees to you, and you pay fees to salesforce.com per license based on your licensing fees.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's really interesting. I'm trying to understand why Veeva and other OEM's are so popular? I don't understand how a good CRM could not have Opportunities, Cases or Leads? I suppose OEM's are far cheaper (a 'pull' factor for customers) but are far more limited. Also, do you know if there are any upfront costs of being an OEM or ISV? With ISV, I think it's at least $3-5k now due to security app review check.  Thanks!

Comment: @AndyHitchings From what I can tell, yes, there are up-front costs, ranging from free to 20,000 USD a year, plus a minimum number of certified developers and required training. That also does not include the security review costs. Your best bet is contact them directly and ask. It's free to just talk to Partner Support.

Comment: @AndyHitchings Also, the reason why no Cases, Opportunities, Leads, Solutions, is that salesforce wants people to pay them directly for CRM. Since OEMs are allowed to charge whatever they want for licenses, you could just mock the objects, for example, and charge 1/10th the cost that salesforce charges, and salesforce would only make 15-25% of that. They still want to make money, but they're willing to share a bit. I guess if you were OEM, your client could still upgrade to get CRM added.

Answer (score 8):

This is a type of OEM application where SF allow user to build app and sell it as per there customization.

The AppExchange OEM Edition nevertheless offers developers a proven and secure platform, which allows them to focus on their product innovation without having to worry about the infrastructure. It allows developers to leverage the SalesForce platform to develop and sell on-demand applications, distinct from the run-of-the-mill CRM apps. They have the freedom to fix their own delivery channels, but cannot use the AppExchange Checkout

You can check it more detail [here](http://suyati.com/which-salesforce-license-should-you-opt-for-isvforce-or-oem/)

Comment: Thank you, @Tushar Sharma. Do you know if there's a way for one to find out all the different OEM providers? Or is this information that Salesforce don't make publically available?